# Why is this script causing "too many open files" error in ElasticSearch with docker?

Tags: node.js, docker, elasticsearch, ulimit

This script gets ran from a cronjob every 15 minutes to index new posts in mongodb to ElasticSearch (all within docker)

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import Post from '../models/post';
import search from '../search';

const log = require('debug');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config();

const debug = log('express-starter:db');

console.log(process.env.MONGO_URI);
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
  keepAlive: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE,
  reconnectInterval: 500,
});
mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => debug('successfully connected to db'));
mongoose.connection.on('error', console.error);

async function getPosts() {
  const posts = await Post.find({}).catch(console.error);

  return posts;
}

async function checkIndices() {
  const { body } = await search.indices.exists({ index: 'posts' });

  console.log(body);

  if (!body) {
    await search.indices.create({ index: 'posts' });
  }
}

let posts = [];
const all = [];
let added = 0;
let updated = 0;
const failed = {
  updates: 0,
  inserts: 0,
}

const queueNext = async () => {
  if (!posts.length) return;
  const post = posts.shift();
  const { body } = await search
    .exists({
      index: 'posts',
      id: post._id,
    })
    .catch(('no post', post._id));

  if (body) {
    console.log('update', post._id);
    updated += 1;
    await search
      .update({
        index: 'posts',
        id: post._id,
        body: { doc: post },
      })
      .catch(err => {
        failed.updates += 1;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err), 'update failed', post._id, post);
      });
  } else {
    // add to elastic search
    added += 1;
    console.log('add', post._id);
    await search
      .index({
        index: 'posts',
        id: post._id,
        body: post,
      })
      .catch(err => {
        failed.inserts += 1;
        console.error(err);
      });
  }

  all.push(post);
  await queueNext();
};

(async () => {
  posts = await getPosts().catch(console.error);

  // console.log(posts);

  await checkIndices();
  await search.indices.refresh({ index: 'posts' });

  await Promise.all(Array.from({ length: 100 }, queueNext));

  console.log(all.length, 'posts found');
  console.log(updated, 'posts updated');
  console.log(added, 'posts added');
  console.log(failed.updates, 'failed updates');
  console.log(failed.inserts, 'failed inserts');

  await search.indices.refresh({ index: 'posts' });
  process.exit(0);
})();
```

There's around 10k documents in mongodb and the script takes only a few seconds to run, but after about 6 hours (i increased files to 65335 from 1024) and it still locks up the entire host OS (Ubuntu 18.04).

Am I doing something wrong here?

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 128199
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 16384
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1000000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 100000
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

If I disable the cronjob, this is what lsof says when sorted by number of files. Before it had elasticsearch at 120k open files.

```
  39744 1071 dockerd
   6528 972 container
   2352 6065 mysqld
   2352 3389 mysqld
   1863 2981 mysqld
    396 8947 node
    308 4638 node
    308 4356 node
    275 7841 node
    275 3947 node
    272 965 transmiss
    268 7095 mongod
    268 5870 mongod
    264 6394 container
    264 6187 mongod
    264 5098 container
    264 4693 container
    264 4601 container
    264 4147 container
    264 3182 container
```